# Product of two infinite summations

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to show
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)\sum_{m=1}^\infty g(m)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty f(n)g(m)\end{equation*}
Do I have to invoke the conditions on Fubini's theorem? Or is this always true?

---

I tried this proof, which does not require absolute convergence, just convergence.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)\sum_{m=1}^\infty g(m)&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Nf(n)\sum_{m=1}^\infty g(m)\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[f(1)\sum_{m=1}^\infty g(m)+...+f(N)\sum_{m=1}^\infty g(m)\right]\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[f(1)\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{m=1}^M g(m)+...+f(N)\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{m=1}^M g(m)\right]\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{m=1}^M f(1)g(m)+...+\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{m=1}^M f(N)g(m)\right]\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\left[\sum_{m=1}^M f(1)g(m)+...+\sum_{m=1}^M f(N)g(m)\right]\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{m=1}^N\sum_{m=1}^M f(n)g(m)\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{m=1}^N\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{m=1}^M f(n)g(m)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(n) g(m)
\end{align*}

Comment: I believe your proof is ok as long as all three summations converge.

Comment: I'm curious if this still works if the sums diverge to infinity

Comment: Generally no, in the following sense: there may be a situation in which the two sums in the LHS are convergent (but not absolutely convergent;  imagine for example alternating signs in each of $f(n)$, $g(n)$) and the sum in the RHS has all its terms positive. In this case it will be divergent, since the summations on $|f(n)|$, $|g(m)|$ will each be divergent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If what you mean is 
$$
\begin{equation*}
\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\sum_{m=1}^\infty g(m)\bigg)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty f(n)g(m)
\end{equation*}
$$
this is always valid, as long as the summations $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$, $ \ \sum_{m=1}^\infty g(m)$ are absolutely convergent or more generally as long as all three summations are convergent: it is a kind of generalized statement of the distributivity of multiplication over addition.

Comment: Yes, I mean multiplication, that is for example, in the case where $\sum f(n)=2$ and $\sum g(m)=3$, then $\sum f(n)\sum g(m)=6$. How can I prove that? Just using limits should work?

Comment: I believe you need all the sums to be absolutely convergent.  Distributivity is written in terms of finite sums and products.  I don't have a handy counterexample with conditionally convergent sums.

Comment: Hmm I think you may have a point here. I mean if the series are absolutely convergent then it seems clear, otherwise it needs a little more care. Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: However, i think it is not necessary to demand absolute convergence for all three sums.

Comment: @KonKan Please see my attempted proof in the edit. I don't use absolute convergence, just convergence,

Comment: Yes I was studying it right now. Looks ok to me. So, you simply assume convergence for alll three summations. This is what I had in mind when I said "a kind of generalized statement of the distributivity".